# ValueChange Event and Ajax saving button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem where I have a field with `ValueChange` ajax event and I have a saving ajax driven button. The problem happens when the user edits the field and then click over the saving button. The first click sends the `ValueChange` ajax request and updates the other fields, the second click saves the form. Here is a sample code

```
<pf:commandButton id="save" value="save" actionListener="#{car.save}">
    <pf:ajax process="@form" update="@form" />
</pf:commandButton>

<pf:inputText id="price" value="#{car.price}">
    <pf:ajax event="valueChange" process="@form" listener="#{car.calculatePrice}" update=":form:totalPrice"/>
</pf:inputText>
```

Is there a way to avoid this scenario ?. I guess one way is to make the saving button a non-ajax button. Is there another solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was somewhere in the project there is a `<p:ajaxStatus>` component that dims the whole website when you want to make @form update. Normally JSF has no problem with this.

In case you use `<p:ajaxStatus>` for your website and you faced the same problem. There is one solution for this, you can use the following code instead of the one mentioned in the question

```
<h:commandButton id="save" value="save">
    <pf:ajax event="mousedown" process="@form" update="@form" listner="#{car.save}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: glad you resolved your issue,  you stil can accept your answer by clicking the check-mark, so that others can benefit from it

Comment: @Tarik: own answers on own questions can only be accepted after 48h (so the community can be given the opportunity to post better answers).